# Join two dataframe columns without repeated combinations

Tags: join, pyspark, inner-join

I want to join the "item" column of  the two dataframes.

```
Dataframe1(df1)
id    item
 1      1
 1      2 
 1      2

Dataframe2(df2)
_id    item
 44    1
 44    2
 44    2
```

I tried inner join, inorder to return the matching values

```
 out= df1.join(df2,  df2.item==df1.item, 'inner')
 +---+----+----+---+
 | id|item|item|_id|
 +---+----+----+---+
 |  1| [1]| [1]| 44|
 |  1| [2]| [2]| 44|
 |  1| [2]| [2]| 44|
 |  1| [2]| [2]| 44|
 |  1| [2]| [2]| 44|
 +---+----+----+---
```

But i want the result like the below without including repeated matching combinations

```
+---+----+----+---+
 | id|item|item|_id|
 +---+----+----+---+
 |  1| [1]| [1]| 44|
 |  1| [2]| [2]| 44|
 |  1| [2]| [2]| 44|
 +---+----+----+---+
```

Another example could be

```
Dataframe1(df1)
id    item
 1      1
 1      2 
 1      1

Dataframe2(df2)
_id    item
 44    1
 44    2
```

The result should be

```
+---+----+----+---+
| id|item|item|_id|
 +---+----+----+---+
 |  1| [1]| [1]| 44|
 |  1| [2]| [2]| 44|
 +---+----+----+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

The most optimized way to achieve this is using  **LEFT SEMI JOIN** -

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1),(1,2),(1,2)],['id','item'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(44,1),(44,2),(44,2)],['id','item'])

df1.join(df2,  df2.item==df1.item, 'left_semi').show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**select distinct a.id, a.item, b.id, b.item
from df1 a 
  inner join df2 b
  on a.item= b.item
order by a.item;**

It will definitely resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `drop_duplicates()`

```
out= df1.join(df2,  df2.item==df1.item, 'inner').drop_duplicates()
```